# What is the best way to pass variables to a json using Terraform

Tags: json, terraform

I have a simple `terraform` module that us using a `json` file as below:

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "ecs_task_definition" {
  container_definitions    = file(var.CONTAINER_DEFINITION_PATH)
  cpu                      = var.TASK_CPU
  execution_role_arn       = var.EXECUTION_ROLE_ARN
  family                   = var.TASK_FAMILY
  memory                   = var.TASK_MEMORY
  network_mode             = var.TASK_NETWORK_MODE
  requires_compatibilities = var.TASK_REQUIRES_COMPATABILITIES

  tags = var.TASK_TAGS

  task_role_arn = var.EXECUTION_ROLE_ARN
}
```

And I am using this module as below:

`main.tf`

```
module "agent_connect_service_ecs_task_definition" {
  source = "./modules/task_definition"

  CONTAINER_DEFINITION_PATH     = "./container_definitions/agent_connect_service.json"
  TASK_CPU                      = "256"
  EXECUTION_ROLE_ARN            = data.aws_iam_role.ecsTaskExecutionRole.arn
  TASK_FAMILY                   = var.AGENT_CONNECT_SERVICE_SERVICE_NAME // change me
  TASK_MEMORY                   = "512"
  TASK_NETWORK_MODE             = "awsvpc"
  TASK_REQUIRES_COMPATABILITIES = ["FARGATE"]
  TASK_TAGS                     = { "Name" : "mlb-agent-connect", "Project" : "mlb"  } // change me
}
```

And here in the json `agent_connect_service.json` I need to dynamically change some values. I have given below **only** a part of the json object for your readability where I need to have the dynamically changing value:

```
[
    {
        "cpu": 0,
        "environment": [
            {
                "name": "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT",
                "value": "<VALUE-I-NEED-TO-CHANGE-DYNAMICALLY>"
            }
        ]
        .
        .
        .
    }
]
```

In the above json, how can I pass some random values to the `VALUE-I-NEED-TO-CHANGE-DYNAMICALLY` section? What is the best possible way I can get this done without really cluttering up the `main.tf` (means, I don't need to define the json file within the `main.tf` because I need that json definition in a different directory as it is now)

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way would be to use [templatefile](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/templatefile.html) and make your `json` into template.

This allows you to pass in your variables into the `templatefile` which will generate your final json.